# My IE toolbar is not selectable

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have created an IE Toolbar using C# in VS 2008.

When I run IE 7 or IE 8 (over Vista Home on a 64 bit laptop) and go View => Toolbars,
I see my toolbar listed (right along with the others, like the Google toolbar) but I cannot put a check mark beside my toolbar.

thanks for whatever help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this means that there was a problem loading your toolbar.  Did you assign a proper strongname?  Did you call regasm?  Did you use GacUtil to install the strongly-named assembly in the GAC?

http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/dotnetbandobjects.asp has a good step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much!  For some reason my toolbar became selectable, but if it ever goes bad again, I have your suggestions to help me out.  And step-by-step tutorials are just my cup of tea.  Thanks!